# Failed to edit persistent store "s3" - with spinnaker storage with s3 configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to configure the spinnaker with hal from the source (https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/hello-deployment/).

While configuring the storage with s3 in aws I am facing the below error.

Someone please guide me to resolve this issue.

> hal config storage s3 edit --access-key-id xxxx --secret-access-key --region us-west-2
>
> Problems in default.persistentStorage.s3:
>
> ! ERROR Failed to ensure the required bucket
> "spin-1889a6d7-dd17-4896-9ef9-e07cc2ab5b2a" exists: Forbidden
> (Service: Amazon   S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden;
> Request ID: xxxx;   S3 Extended Request ID:   xxx
>
> - Failed to edit persistent store "s3".

Answer (score 0):

You should have proper(read,write) permission to s3.

1. Check your permission on IAM console.
2. Make sure you have read,write access to s3.
3. More on IAM policies: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's too late to answer. Anyway, official documentation says that there a possibility to specify bucket, using `--bucket`

Seems like you have not configured a bucket for your deployment. Create a bucket first, and provide hal it's name. I had synonymic issue when I was adding my `--endpoint` incorrectly (not full URI)

Use something like this:

```
hal config storage s3 edit --endpoint https://<domain_s3>:<port> --bucket <bucket_name> --access-key-id <key_id> --secret-access-key <secret_key> --path-style-access true --deployment <your_deployment>
```

```
hal config storage edit --type s3 --deployment <your_deployment>
```